# Initializing the argument in NUnit 'TestCase' attribute

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

I haven't seen this on their Documentations, but I am looking to do a test like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SampleModel
{
    // stuff

    [TestCase(new DBContext(), 502)]
    public IQueryable<SomeModel> GetPrograms(DBContext dbContext, int? programId)
    {
        // Assert stuff
    }
}
```

Is it possible to initialize an argument in `TestCase` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible for `TestCase` attribute.
C# attributes accept constant only parameters.

But this is possible with [`TestCaseSource`](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki/TestCaseSource-Attribute) attribute:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SampleModel
{
    // stuff

    static object [] GetProgramsCases {
        new object[] { new DBContext(), 502 }
    };


    [TestCaseSource("GetProgramsCases")]
    public IQueryable<SomeModel> GetPrograms(DBContext dbContext, int? programId)
    {
        // Assert stuff
    }
}
```